# casting double to signed vs unsigned integer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

It seem that the MSVC Compiler treats signed and unsigned overflow differnetly. When casting a double value that exceeds the maximum integer value, the result is the smallest possible integer value (always the same). When casting to unsigned int, the cast produces an overflow as expected (maximum unsigned int value + 1 produces 0, maximum unsigned int + 2 produces 1, ...)
Can someone explain the behaviour of the compiler, or is it a bug?

Tested compilers MSVC 10 and 14

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Tests
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_overflow_signed) {
  double d_int_max_1 = INT_MAX + 1.; //2147483647 + 1
  double d_int_max_2 = INT_MAX + 2.; //2147483647 + 2

  BOOST_CHECK((int)(2147483648.) != (int)(2147483649.)); //succeeds (overflows to -2147483648 and -2147483647)
  BOOST_CHECK((int)(d_int_max_1) != (int)(d_int_max_2)); //fails (both values overflow to -2147483648)
  std::cout << "(int)(2147483648.) == " << (int)(2147483648.) << std::endl; //-2147483648
  std::cout << "(int)(2147483649.) == " << (int)(2147483649.) << std::endl; //-2147483647
  std::cout << "(int)(d_int_max_1) == " << (int)(d_int_max_1) << std::endl; //-2147483648
  std::cout << "(int)(d_int_max_2) == " << (int)(d_int_max_2) << std::endl; //-2147483648
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_overflow_unsigned) {
  double d_int_max_1 = UINT_MAX + 1.;//4294967295 + 1
  double d_int_max_2 = UINT_MAX + 2.;//4294967295 + 2
  //BOOST_CHECK((unsigned int)(4294967296.) != (unsigned int)(4294967297.)); //compiler fails (!= truncation of constant value)
  BOOST_CHECK((unsigned int)(d_int_max_1) != (unsigned int)(d_int_max_2)); //succeeds (overflows to 0 and 1)
  std::cout << "(unsigned int)(d_int_max_1) == " << (unsigned int)(d_int_max_1) << std::endl; //0
  std::cout << "(unsigned int)(d_int_max_2) == " << (unsigned int)(d_int_max_2) << std::endl; //1
}
```

Comment: "weirded behavior" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: i hope the question is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[conv.fpint]/1** A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
>   represented in the destination type.**

Emphasis mine. Since the behavior is undefined, any outcome whatsoever is correct.

Comment: thanks for solving out the mistery for me. not knowing that the compiler behaves different for casting floating values to unsigned and signed integer types made it very hard for me to track down a bug.

Comment: There is no difference - the behavior is undefined either way, whether you cast to `int` or `unsigned`.

Comment: the implemented behaviour of the msvc compiler is different. unsigned int overflows, signed int is set to INT_MIN in case of casting a too large floating value.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Its specific manifestation on a particular version of a particular compiler is irrelevant - or at least, it should be, because a correct C++ program would not exhibit undefined behavior in the first place. You are not thinking of writing production code that relies on it, are you?

Comment: i had to debug production code that resulted in undefined behavior. not knowing that double to int cast can result in undefined behavior, made it difficult to find the bug. indeed the cast was not necessary in the code and removing the cast and using double types fixed to bug. so no worries, i don't want to have undefined behavior in my code. debugging undefined behavior causes some headache thought.